# Firestore query after adding composite index still return nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have already created react app and I'm using firebase firestore.
So at the start of using I didn't have any problems, until I found that I need to create a query like that:

```
db.collection('schedule')
            .where('working_day', '>=', new Date())
            .where('master', '==', masterId)
            .orderBy('working_day', 'desc')
            .get();
```

I have a collection called **schedule** and this **schedule** collection has list of **documents**. Each **document** has structure:

```
working_day: timestamp;
start_hour: number;
end_hour: number;
master: string;
```

When I called this query - I didn't see any result (request is gone, but no results at all). Someone suggest me to add composite indexing and It must solve this problem
I did it using firestore indexing tab and now I have this indexing:

```
Collection ID   Fields indexed                          Query scope     Status
schedule    working_day Descending master Descending    Collection      Enabled
```

It has been successfully applied - but still my request without any result.
Also I know that firestore could notice me that I need to apply this indexing and provide me the link - but I don't see this link. Where I should find this? Or maybe I do something wrong?

Break my head for the 2 days and didn't find why I have this issue

Comment: I also tried different variants of indexing and order by any field - no result anyway

Comment: The message asking you to create a composite index will appear in the web developer console when no proper index matches a query. You could try deleting the current indexes to check if it appears. I quickly tested recreating your documents and query, and I did see the message, created the index (allowed it to build), and then actually got the documents fetched. Have you made sure that this query will match documents in your database in case there is still no output?

Comment: Why `master Descending` and not `master Ascending`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `working.day` is stored in your firestore database as a timestamp but your query condition is comparing against a javascript date object which could be causing an issue. Try replacing the date object with a firebase timestamp like the code below.

```
db.collection('schedule')
            .where('working_day', '>=',  new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now())
            .where('master', '==', masterId)
            .orderBy('working_day', 'desc')
            .get();
```